# Child's attribute depends on parent's attribute in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

Considering below xml code

```
<panel col="2">
    <label value="old password" />
    <text id="oldPass" />
</panel>
```

now I want to declare a XSD file for above xml, and I want when panel's attribute col greater than zero, all of the elements inside it have special colspan attribute and when it is not true they don't have colspan attribute.

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2):

In XSD 1.1, inside your `complexType` of `panel` you could use `assertion` test

```
<xs:assert test="(@col > 0)  and (./child::*[@colspan])"/>
<xs:assert test="(@col <= 0)  and (count(./child::*[@colspan]) = 0)"/>
```

Comment: I use eclipce Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), and when I put that snipped code inside complexType I get this error -->  s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_priceProduct' is invalid. Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

Comment: I'm afraid eclipse validation is in 1.0 and the issue is still here  : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312163